# Playing video from temp url iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, media-player

I want to play a video in seprate view controller, where I can Play/Pause or dismiss that view controller. In my case, I recorded the video in my app and calling this delegate method in order to save this video in assets, but I want to play it first before using the `ALAssetsLibrary`.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
      fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
                error:(NSError *)error
```

And the TEMO URL im getting is :

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EA6D31AC-6CC3-4BDF-B874-BC6F30BA5677/tmp/output.mov
```

How can I play this video in next view controller or in same view controller??

My try:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:outputFileURL];
        player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
        [self.view addSubview:player.view];
        [player play];
```

PS: This is showing a black screen area but not actually playing this video.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago. It ends up that I was calling play method to soon, before the video become ready to play. So, add this before call [player play]. This will notify whenever your video become read to play in MPMoviePlayerController.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
```

Then setup the observer:

```
- (void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

}
```

This worked for me.

Hope it helps.